# Font used in foxpro application

Tags: foxpro

I want to know is there any way to know which font a foxpro application using for printing. This foxpro application is around 8-10 yrs old. and when I print bill it produces same font style in (XP, Win7 os). I want to this font because it produces good result than what i experimented with different font available on Win 7 OS.

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall the old days, FoxPro is rendering it's own "fonts" (it's not using system fonts).
Depending on what version of FoxPro are you talking about, it might be possible to find them in some of the FoxPro installation directories, but I doubt that you could use them directly as a system font since I'm almost sure they're not true type fonts.

If you need these fonts badly however, than you could re-create them as TrueTypeFonts with a little work:
 - form FoxPro do some reports to print all letters and symbols at bigger sizes (but various too - to see the scale ranges)
 - print all of them on the paper and scan them back (or use a print driver to capture the images)
 - Use an advanced Font Editor to create them, and put those scanned font images as an background underlay to easily and quickly made them based on the contour of the FoxPro fonts.

This is basically how most Font creators do their font too: they draw by hand the some sketches, than use them as background/under-layer in a Font Editor.

Comment: This is not the case and never has been - FoxPro uses the fonts installed in Windows like anything else. When printing the font or fonts used on the report layout definition will be used. Still Windows fonts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the report file containing the report definition (it will be a .frx file) then you can open that in a DBF viewer and see the font used - alternatively take a screenshot to http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to see if it can identify it.

Answer (score 0):

If the font output is the same independent of OS, and without you having to install a font, then it's probably one of the core Microsoft fonts. If it's monospaced it's probably Courier New.